# How to implement synchronization for files and folders using wcf

Tags: .net, wcf, file, synchronization

I would like to implement synchronization for client server architecture.

**For Client** : Planning to create a windows application.
**For Server** : Planning to create a Wcf service

my client app will call the service and retrieve the folders and files.Now i can do modify/add the files/folders locally.

Then i will sync it to the server.Before sync process, my client app should show a preview like what are the files have already updated in the server by some other user.

My question is:
             **Is WCF flexible for this business requirement? Since my data is too secure and too large,I have to choose right architecture.**

Please share your thoughts?

Comment: Do you have multiple clients / users that modify the same files & folders? If so, it may be complex to implement the change-tracking / merging, etc.

Comment: Is a version control system like GIT/SVN an option?

Comment: Multiple clients is an option in future.But right now i need a basic struture. The problem why i am not able to go svn is that we have to fetch values from database for files and folders and user group level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only want to know about WCF being the right technology within the solution then i would say that WCF or Windows Communication foundation is just a communication mechanism exposed on .Net framework. For the problem you have described this would be just a small component with the complete architecture.
The problem here is similar to source control systems workflow, and if you look at Microsoft TFS architecture [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252473%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)  you will found that TFS functionality too has been exposed over web services\WCF services. So i think WCF can do the heavy lifting w.r.t your requirement.